# Regex Doesn't Match Beyond 1st Result

Tags: python, regex

I'm using Python to match against a list (array), but I'm sure the problem lies on the regex itself.

Assuming I have the following:

```
foo.html
bar.html
teep.html
```

And I use the following regex: `.*(?=.html)`

where `.*` will match anything and `(?=.html)` requires the string be present, but does not include it in the results

Thus, I should just be left with what's before `.html`

When I check, it only matches the first item in the array (in this case `foo`), but why not the others

```
my_regex = re.compile('.html$')
r2 = re.compile('.*(?=.html)')
start = '/path/to/folder'
os.chdir(start)
a = os.listdir(start)
for item in a:
    if my_regex.search(item) != None and os.path.isdir(item):
        print 'FOLDER MATCH: '+ item # this is a folder and not a file
        starterPath = os.path.abspath(item)
        outer_file = starterPath + '/index.html'
        outer_js = starterPath + '/outliner.js'
        if r2.match(item) != None:
            filename = r2.match(item).group() # should give me evertying before .html
        makePage(outer_file, outer_js, filename) # self defined function
    else:
        print item + ': no'
```

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew added

Comment: Well, `r'.*(?=\.html)'` is a better regex for you, but the main issue is not with a regex.

Comment: Can you elaborate further? My script is going through each item in the list, and it has 2 items that the regex should pick up and match. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help much here, you need to debug your code yourself. Note that `'.html$'` pattern matches `9html` at the end of the string. To match a dot, you need to escape it in the pattern.

Comment: Thank you, I did forget about escaping the '.' but I'm pretty sure the python end is okay. I only say this because if i use a tool like http://regexr.com/, it only matches the first result there as well.

Comment: Do not pay attention to regex testers (where all you need is to enable the `g` modifier to find multiple matches), you need to check your code and input.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you were absolutely right, it was indeed my code causing the problem, not the regex. In my function, I changed directories so back in my for loop, it was looking in wrong location for folder name.

Answer (score 1):

```
filename = r2.match(item).group()
```

should be

```
filename = r2.match(item).groups()  # plural !
```

According to the documentation, [`group`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.match.group) will return *one or more subgroups*, whereas [`groups`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.match.groups) will return them all.

Comment: See my answer for update. `.groups()` unfortunately did work but turns out it wasn't causing the problem. Just a simple rookie developer mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem. In my function, I changed directories, but never changed back. So when function ended and went back to for loop, it was now looking for the folder name in the wrong location. It's as simple as

```
def makePage(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    os.chdir('path/to/desktop')
    # write file to new location
    os.chdir(start)  # go back to start and continue original search
    return
```

Also `.group()` worked for me and returned everything in the folder name before the string `.html` whereas `.groups()` just returned `()`

The code in original post stayed the same. Something so simple, causing all this headache..